# Get active sessions with wmi (Win32_LogonSession returns also inactive/old sessions)

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, interactive-session

Is there a way to show only active sessions with wmi?
The problem is that Win32_LogonSession shows also inactive/disconnected sessions.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_LogonSession");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in results)
{
    PrintWmiObject(mo);
}
```

The output of this is something like this

> AuthenticationPackage - Kerberos
>
> Caption -
>
> Description -
>
> InstallDate -
>
> LogonId - 10179411
>
> LogonType - 10
>
> Name -
>
> StartTime - 20110617083244.547220+120
>
> Status -

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 10")
```

Comment: It doesn't show whether the session is active or not