# How to find the session name of the logged in Windows user?

Tags: c#

As you can see in the tab user of the windows task manager, there are 5 columns :

```
User   ID   Status  Client Name  Session
Mike   1    Active               Console
```

I have used this to get the session id :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.ToString();
```

I want to know the session name to see if it is console or remote desktop or etc.

```
private string getsessionname()
{
  // function to get session name
}

if(getsessionname=="console")
{
  // do staff1
}
else
{
  // do staff2
}
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c)

Comment: no, I thought that but it says "session name"

Comment: i want the seesion name of currnet user not the username. they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting the session name and then testing for certain values, are you not just looking for [`SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

> Gets a value indicating whether the calling process is associated with a Terminal Services client session.

E.g.:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

if(SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
{
  // do stuff where the user is using remote desktop
}
else
{
  // user is connected locally, e.g. the console
}
```

Comment: can you explain more with example ? i am newbie. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no managed API. One way is to use the native API via P-Invoke, see [Retrieving Logon Session Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379437%28VS.85%29.aspx). But a much easier way is to use WMI and [query the Win32_LogonSession object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438515/105929).

Comment: thanks but the  easier way gets these results : \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="995"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="999"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="997"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="996"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="146406"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="224478"
\\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="709133"
not the things i want to get. by the way thanks for your effort.